# Next Js static assets give 500 internal server error when deployed to Plesk

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js, web-hosting, plesk

I have deployed a next-js app to plesk hosting and after a shed ton of tinkering managed to get it working. However it is returning 500 internal server errors in the console when requesting the static assets, see example below:

```
GET https://nextjs-test.reachtest.co.uk/_next/static/css/120f2e2270820d49a21f.css [HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error 11ms]
```

As this is just for testing, it is quite simply just the initial `npx create-next-app`.

Link: https://nextjs-test.reachtest.co.uk/

In order to get the App even running I had to copy the start script from nextjs and point all of the requires back to node_modules and change the defaultCommand from:

```
next dev
```

to:

```
next start
```

See the file below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
"use strict"; var log = _interopRequireWildcard(require("./node_modules/next/dist/build/output/log.js")); var _index = _interopRequireDefault(require("./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/arg/index.js")); var _constants = require("./node_modules/next/dist/lib/constants"); function _interopRequireDefault(obj) { return obj && obj.__esModule ? obj : { default: obj }; } function _getRequireWildcardCache() { if (typeof WeakMap !== "function") return null; var cache = new WeakMap(); _getRequireWildcardCache = function () { return cache; }; return cache; } function _interopRequireWildcard(obj) { if (obj && obj.__esModule) { return obj; } if (obj === null || typeof obj !== "object" && typeof obj !== "function") { return { default: obj }; } var cache = _getRequireWildcardCache(); if (cache && cache.has(obj)) { return cache.get(obj); } var newObj = {}; var hasPropertyDescriptor = Object.defineProperty && Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor; for (var key in obj) { if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, key)) { var desc = hasPropertyDescriptor ? Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj, key) : null; if (desc && (desc.get || desc.set)) { Object.defineProperty(newObj, key, desc); } else { newObj[key] = obj[key]; } } } newObj.default = obj; if (cache) { cache.set(obj, newObj); } return newObj; } ['react', 'react-dom'].forEach(dependency => {
    try {// When 'npm link' is used it checks the clone location. Not the project.
        require.resolve(dependency);
    } catch (err) { console.warn(`The module '${dependency}' was not found. Next.js requires that you include it in 'dependencies' of your 'package.json'. To add it, run 'npm install ${dependency}'`); }
}); const defaultCommand = 'start'; const commands = { build: () => Promise.resolve().then(() => _interopRequireWildcard(require('./node_modules/next/dist/cli/next-build'))).then(i => i.nextBuild), start: () => Promise.resolve().then(() => _interopRequireWildcard(require('./node_modules/next/dist/cli/next-start'))).then(i => i.nextStart), export: () => Promise.resolve().then(() => _interopRequireWildcard(require('./node_modules/next/dist/cli/next-export'))).then(i => i.nextExport), dev: () => Promise.resolve().then(() => _interopRequireWildcard(require('./node_modules/next/dist/cli/next-dev'))).then(i => i.nextDev), lint: () => Promise.resolve().then(() => _interopRequireWildcard(require('./node_modules/next/dist/cli/next-lint'))).then(i => i.nextLint), telemetry: () => Promise.resolve().then(() => _interopRequireWildcard(require('./node_modules/next/dist/cli/next-telemetry'))).then(i => i.nextTelemetry) }; const args = (0, _index.default)({// Types
    '--version': Boolean, '--help': Boolean, '--inspect': Boolean,// Aliases
    '-v': '--version', '-h': '--help'
}, { permissive: true });// Version is inlined into the file using taskr build pipeline
if (args['--version']) { console.log(`Next.js v${"11.0.1"}`); process.exit(0); }// Check if we are running `next <subcommand>` or `next`
const foundCommand = Boolean(commands[args._[0]]);// Makes sure the `next --help` case is covered
// This help message is only showed for `next --help`
// `next <subcommand> --help` falls through to be handled later
if (!foundCommand && args['--help']) {
    console.log(`
        Usage
          $ next <command>
    
        Available commands
          ${Object.keys(commands).join(', ')}
    
        Options
          --version, -v   Version number
          --help, -h      Displays this message
    
        For more information run a command with the --help flag
          $ next build --help
      `); process.exit(0);
} const command = foundCommand ? args._[0] : defaultCommand; const forwardedArgs = foundCommand ? args._.slice(1) : args._; if (args['--inspect']) throw new Error(`--inspect flag is deprecated. Use env variable NODE_OPTIONS instead: NODE_OPTIONS='--inspect' next ${command}`);// Make sure the `next <subcommand> --help` case is covered
if (args['--help']) { forwardedArgs.push('--help'); } const defaultEnv = command === 'dev' ? 'development' : 'production'; const standardEnv = ['production', 'development', 'test']; if (process.env.NODE_ENV && !standardEnv.includes(process.env.NODE_ENV)) { log.warn(_constants.NON_STANDARD_NODE_ENV); }; process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || defaultEnv;// this needs to come after we set the correct NODE_ENV or
// else it might cause SSR to break
const React = require('react'); if (typeof React.Suspense === 'undefined') { throw new Error(`The version of React you are using is lower than the minimum required version needed for Next.js. Please upgrade "react" and "react-dom": "npm install react react-dom" https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/invalid-react-version`); }// Make sure commands gracefully respect termination signals (e.g. from Docker)
process.on('SIGTERM', () => process.exit(0)); process.on('SIGINT', () => process.exit(0)); commands[command]().then(exec => exec(forwardedArgs)).then(() => {
    if (command === 'build') {// ensure process exits after build completes so open handles/connections
        // don't cause process to hang
        process.exit(0);
    }
}); if (command === 'dev') { const { CONFIG_FILE } = require('./node_modules/next/dist/next-server/lib/constants'); const { watchFile } = require('fs'); watchFile(`${process.cwd()}/${CONFIG_FILE}`, (cur, prev) => { if (cur.size > 0 || prev.size > 0) { console.log(`\n> Found a change in ${CONFIG_FILE}. Restart the server to see the changes in effect.`); } }); }
    //# sourceMappingURL=next.map
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue while deploying my next.js app to staging server, and the solution was simple:

```
// rebuild and restart your app
npm i
npm run build
npm start
```

in my case it was due to .next folder was pointing to some old release.